# $(M,d)$ is complete iff all closed and countable subspace of $M$ is complete

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

A metric space $(M,d)$ is complete $\iff$ if every closed and countable subspace $F\subseteq M$ is complete.

$\implies)$ For this implication I use a proposition that says: "If $X$ is a complete metric space and $F \subseteq X$ is closed, then $F$ is complete". But for $\impliedby )$ I don't know what to do.

Comment: Start with taking a Cauchy sequence. Can you see what to do next?

Comment: yes, prove that it is a convergent sequence in $M$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Daniel Fischer, consider the set $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$, where $\{a_i\}_{i>0}$ is a Cauchy sequence. A Cauchy sequence has at most one limit point, so the closure $\overline{A}$ is still countable as it contains at most one extra point. By hypothesis, $\overline{A}$ is complete because it is a closed countable subset, hence the Cauchy sequence converges to a limit $a\in\overline{A}$. Thus the Cauchy sequence converges to $a$ in $M$ as well. Since this is true for any Cauchy sequence, $M$ is complete.

Comment: Why a Cauchy sequence has at most one limit point?

Comment: @ArielMarceloPardo Suppose there were two limit points $x\neq y$, with $d(x,y)=a$. Choose $N$ so large that $d(x,a_n)<a/2$ and $d(y,a_n)<a/2$ for all $n>N$ (which is possible by the definition of a Cauchy sequence). Then $a=d(x,y)\leq d(x,a_n)+d(y,a_n)<a$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Every Cauchy sequence has a limit point?

Comment: @ArielMarceloPardo At most one. It could also have no limit point if the space were not complete.

Comment: ok, in @Matt Samuel answer, A is complete, i forget that.

Comment: why is important to have a countable subset?

Comment: The hypothesis is only that every closed countable subset is complete. If somehow the closure of $A$ were uncountable, we couldn't apply the condition, so we had to rule out that possibility.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25767/discussion-between-ariel-marcelo-pardo-and-matt-samuel).